# Prove or disprove whether this is a vector space:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = F_3×F_3$ be the direct product of the field of three elements with itself. Define + as componentwise
multiplication of the elements, for example $$(a, b) + (c, d) = (a ∗ c, b ∗ d).$$ Let $F = F_3$ and have scalar
multiplication defined as usual (component wise).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What could be the "additive" identity element??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a vector space.  A vector space must have an identity element for vector addition,

say $(c,d)$ in $V$, satisfying $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a*c,b*d)=(a,b)$.

Furthermore, each vector must have an additive inverse.

But $a* c=a$ and $b* d=b$ for $a,b\in F_3\setminus \{0\}$ imply $(c,d)=(1,1).$

and since $(0,0)+(e,f)=(0
*e,0*f)=(0,0)$ for all $e,f\in F_3$,

there is no additive inverse for $(0,0)$ in your proposed vector space.